# .htaccess регулярное выражение в header

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess

Есть параметр для доступа с суб-домена:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://as.site.com"
```

Можно ли использовать рег. выражение для любого поддомена сайта и основного адреса в этой строке?

На подобии `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin ^https://(.*\.)site.com$`

Comment: Нет. Нельзя. С чего взяли, что можно. Причем тут `.htaccess`?

Comment: @TotalPusher как при чем? если правило прописывать хотят в `.htaccess`. `Header set` это из `mod_headers`

Comment: вероятно задачу можно решить вместе с модулем `mod_setenvif`

Comment: ТС свалил все в одну кучу: заголовки который отдает веб-сервер и обработку этих заголовков в браузере. Так при чем тут .htaccess, если мы говорим о браузере?

Comment: @TotalPusher код прописывается в .htaccess что тут не понятного?

Comment: @Владимир Хорошо, код прописали. Браузер получил заголовок `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin ^https://(.*\.)site.com"`. Как браузер должен обработать этот запрос?

Comment: Если по частям, то `Header` в .htaccess указывать можно, но в вашем случае пока не ясно зачем. Header очень простая директива - сформировать HTTP-заголовок от сервера клиенту. Всё. Вы явно не дописали в вопрос, как у вас происходит (в каком месте) "вычисление" - откуда пришел запрос. Если, например, запрос пришел с суб-домена на основной, то где происходит процесс "доступа с суб-домена". Пока не ясно. Напишите больше подробностей.

Comment: Мне кажется у человека итак всё работает, просто он хочет указать сразу несколько поддоменов в параметре, чтобы не дублировать код с каждой новой строки для нового домена

Comment: @Владимир, вот смотрите, как ТС ставит вопрос: `Можно ли использовать рег. выражение для любого поддомена сайта и основного адреса в этой строке?`. Да, прописать можно, веб-серверу фиолетово, но браузер это не поймет. Поэтому нет, нельзя. Я так понял вопрос ТС.

Comment: @TotalPusher да мне кажется примерно так. Вопрос "можно" наверное и подразумевает под собой -  будет ли это работать или нет.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, не в качестве ответа, но может быть вам будет полезно

```
SetEnvIf Host "(([a-z]+\.)example.com)" SubDomain=$1
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{SubDomain}e"  env=SubDomain
```

при включенных `mod_setenvif` и, конечно, `mod_header`, выставит заголовок с текущим доменом запроса для всех `*.example.com`.

не знаю, правда, насколько это грамотное решение, не специалист в области настроек сервера.

---

а без проверки ругляркой то же выставить заголовк для текущего домена можно через

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{HTTP_HOST}s"
```